# How to store all saved values of a field on User entity?

Tags: 8, users

We plan to store a string as a field on a user account page. This is easy to do, but requirement is also to be able to track value changes of the field.

Based on my restricted knowledge in Drupal, this sounds like having revisions for a User entity, which is not supported in Drupal 8, is it?

How can I achieve my goal? Is it possible to create some kind of field that could show all the saved values on the user page (doesn't matter that much), but won't allow users to change them after saving, like a multi-value field that allows only to add new values, but not change or remove values.

Comment: FWIW : there seem to be a dev version for drupal 8 for user_revision : https://www.drupal.org/project/user_revision

Comment: Since the user entity doesn't support revisions and the module mentioned by @izus is not ready for production yet (modules changing the database should only be used when stable), use an extra entity, either custom or this module https://www.drupal.org/project/profile

Comment: OR create a new content type and store the value on a node and then use entity reference to link it to the user.